# how to move switch store to header on magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, store-switcher

I created a child for the luma theme and created  multi store for change language.
how to move store switcher from footer to a header ( i am using magento 2.3)

Answer (score 0):

Then open the default.xml file to edit and insert the code you see below before the  tag.

```
<move element="name.of.an.element" destination="name.of.destination.element" as="new_alias" after="name.of.element.after" before="name.of.element.before"/>
```

For Ex:-

```
<move element="footer.panel.container" destination="header.switchers" after="-"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be specific,

```
<move element="store_switcher" destination="header-wrapper" />
```

Use before or after to position your store switcher.